# Flutter: Image to Base64 conversion output is truncated

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I am trying to convert an image to base64 but conversion is happening only 10% approximately. Remaining output is truncating somehow or not converting.

```
 Future getImage() async {
  var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  setState(() {  
    _image = image;
    print('Image Path $_image');
    List<int> imageBytes = _image.readAsBytesSync();
        String base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);
        print(base64Image);
  });
}
```

Comment: True. The console will truncate the output at about 1000 characters.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks @Richard Heap. Base64 value is truncated in console